# Reading Only 1st Character from String Stored in Vector

Tags: c++, sorting

I am currently working on a programming assignment in which I am supposed to recreate a section of text from a concordance. I would like to first sort all of the lines of text based off line/verse number. Here is what the a sample concordance looks like (the numbers indicate verses):

```
6 and I will *dwell in the house of
5 presence of my *enemies. You anoint my 
4 I will fear no *evil, for you are 
6 and love will *follow me all the days
6 Surely your *goodness and love will 
3 my soul. He *guides me along
5 You anoint my *head with oil; my cup 
1 shepherd, I *lack nothing.
```

Using the code below, I have read each line from the file into a vector.

```
string inFileName;
ifstream conFile;
vector<string> conVec;
string info;

cout << "Welcome to the Concordance sorter!\n";
cout << "Please enter the file you would like to sort:\n\n";

cin >> inFileName;

conFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

if (conFile)
{

    while (!conFile.eof())
    {
        while (getline(conFile, info))
        {
            conVec.push_back(info);
        }   
    }

    conFile.close();
}
```

Is there any way for me to just look at the first character of the string (the verse number) and then use this to sort the vector into numerical order? I know how the sorting would happen, I just do not know how to just use the first character from the string, or if there even is a way to do that at all. Any advice would help greatly!

Comment: Access first char with `conVec[i][0]`

Comment: Thanks, this worked well.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the type of `conVec` and `info`, but if the type of `conVec`'s elements is `char*` or `std::string`, the first character of the string can be accesed by `conVec[index][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function to help you out like this:

```
bool sortVector(char *a, char *b) {
   return *a < *b;
}
```

and call it like

```
std::sort(conVec.start(), conVec.end(), sortVector);
```

This will work with either chars or std::strings, just set the type right.